# No funciona Scanner.next

Tags: while, scanner

> Se pretende que el bloque  while se repita si la condición sigue siendo verdadera y finalice en caso contrario. Para evaluar la condición he creado una booleana. Se solicita si se desea seguir introduciendo datos y un flujo Scanner lo espera. He probado dos opciones, la segunda, que está comentada, funciona bien, con el compareTo, pero la primera opción no funciona de ninguna manera y si alguien tuviera la amabilidad de ilustrarme estaría muy agradecido.

```
      Boolean y=true;

      while(y) {

    System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 1 desea declarar?");
    v1.cant1=v1.cant1+entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 2 desea declarar?");
    v1.cant2=v1.cant2+entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 3 desea declarar?");
    v1.cant3=v1.cant3+entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 4 desea declarar?");
    v1.cant4=v1.cant4+entrada.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Desea declarar mas artículos?. Escriba 'y/Y' para declarar"); 

    if(entrada.next()!="y") y=false;
    //if(entrada.next().compareToIgnoreCase("y")!=0) y=false;


    }
    entrada.close();
    System.out.println( v1.getSalario() + " $ es la cantidad que percibirá esta semana. Que pase un buen día " + v1.getNombre(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para comparar el contenido de dos instancias de [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) debes hacer uso del método [`String.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

```
if (entrada.next().equals("y") == false) {
    /* ... */
}
```

En caso contrario estás comparando dos instancias de `String` distintas, que serán siempre diferentes aunque contengan la misma cadena de caracteres en su interior.

Código usado para reproducir tu problema (pulsa para mostrar):

```js
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    static class v {
        int cant1, cant2, cant3, cant4;
        int getSalario() { return cant1 + cant2 + cant3 + cant4; }
        String getNombre() { return "Oscar"; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        v v1 = new v();
        Boolean y = true;

        while (y) {
            System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 1 desea declarar?");
            v1.cant1 = v1.cant1 + entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 2 desea declarar?");
            v1.cant2 = v1.cant2 + entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 3 desea declarar?");
            v1.cant3 = v1.cant3 + entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Que cantidad de artículos 4 desea declarar?");
            v1.cant4 = v1.cant4 + entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Desea declarar mas artículos?. Escriba 'y/Y' para declarar");
            /* Aquí usamos "equals()" para la comparación */
            if (entrada.next().equals("y") == false) {
                y = false;
            }
        }
        entrada.close();
        System.out.println( v1.getSalario() + " $ es la cantidad que percibirá esta semana. Que pase un buen día " + v1.getNombre());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te da error porque next() no retorna un String comparable con "y".
El método que debes usar para leer un String con la clase escáner es nextLine().

Con cambiar eso debería bastar

Comment: nextLine(); fue mi primera opción pero ni siquiera bloquea el input esperando la nueva entrada. No se si es por que salta el carácter introducido y ya no hay nada más o no se porqué, pero con nextLine(); no va

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de usar equial, compareToIgnoreCase o compareto para string nunca == no uses nextINT
si usas el next int es posible que se salte linea por saturacion del buffer ya que no limpia el retorno de carro, usa Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine)